# How to check file size in multipart/form-data content-type

Tags: erlang, multipartform-data, cowboy

I want to upload files through the multipart/form-data content type.
I can see the whole content size (content-length) but would like to know the size of each part when I upload 3 files (for example)

This is how I get the files:

```
multipart(Req0) ->
  case cowboy_req:read_part(Req0) of
    {ok, Headers, Req1} ->
      ?LOG_WARNING("Headers: p~n", [Headers]),
      {ok, _Body, Req} = cowboy_req:read_part_body(Req1),
      multipart(Req);
    {done, Req} ->
      ?LOG_WARNING("Req: p~n", [Req]),
      Req
  end.
```

But there is no data for size of a file

Is there anyway to get this info? (Instead of checking list length)